# How to programatically add Roles to cloud build service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-build, google-iam

I am trying to use setIAMPolicy for Cloud Build Service account @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com. I want to provide AppEngine Admin, Cloud Run Admin permissions to the Cloud Build Service member so that it can do automated releases on AppEngine.

Somehow it throws 404 when I pass resource of Cloud Build Service account while getting IAM Policy. To confirm, I tried GET [https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/{name=projects/*}/serviceAccounts](https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/%7Bname=projects/*%7D/serviceAccounts) in API Explorer and it also does not return the Google Managed Service accounts. It seems it only returns the service accounts which are created and not the Google Managed default accounts.

How can I set IAM Policy to grant these permissions to Cloud Build?

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to enable these permissions for both [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account#granting_a_role_using_the_settings_page) and [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run#required_iam_permissions).

Also, a common problem is not knowing that cron permissions are needed for App Engine and Cloud build. For example, [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/roles#predefined_roles_comparison_matrix) article mentions "Update cron schedules" as "No" for "App Engine Admin". Whether you need that or not depends on how your builds are done. If you end-up needing that too, use permission "Cloud Scheduler Admin" on your @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com. You can apply the same logic to other permissions and [that](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/roles#predefined_roles_comparison_matrix) chart might be useful for knowing what is needed depending on your setup.

Comment: My question is not about required permissions. I want to set those permissions programmatically. I am able to do it for the Service account I created but I am unable to set the permissions for Google Managed Service account.